# Android - Error Multiple dex files with GCM library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I need to support GCM in my app, but i can't even run it because of this error:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService;
```

I followed Google instructions but at first I added the .jar file as external library from the build path, then I read that I need to add the file to the /libs folder, so i removed from the path and added in the /libs folder. Now i get this error, if I remove the gcm.jar file the app runs, if I add it back it doesen't even start.
I tried cleaning up the project, updating Android SDK but nothing solved that
I'm running Eclipse Version: 3.7.2

Comment: Also i controlled: I have only ONE gcm.jar file in /libs

Comment: Does a project you include also export this library?  If so, you'll hit this problem and need to remove it from this project (keep it in the other).

Comment: I include android-support-v4, android-support-v7-gridlayout and android-zoom-view.